# Can an Access 2007 Macro determine the name of itself..?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Can an Access 2007 macro determine its own object name..?

My database relies heavily on Navigation Pane custom groups, some with hundreds or objects. I would like to create a generic macro that I can copy, rename, and drop into any group, which would perform actions best summarized as "do this task with every other object in this group".

To do so, the macro would need to be aware of its own name, so the MSysNavPane* groups could be queried for that name, and then the work could proceed from there.

I seem to recall that it's difficult if not impossible for VBA procedures to know their own names, but I couldn't find any information on this topic about Access macros.

Comment: I don't use macros, only VBA. Why using macros? Not fully understanding what you are trying to accomplish but will offer that procedures can have custom arguments. Procedure name could be an argument for the 'generic' procedure. When the procedure is called, pass a name as parameter. Why would there be a need to copy the same procedure to multiple groups? Why couldn't there be just the one procedure with arguments?

Comment: @June7 is right; when you feel this kind of needs, it's time to leave the macros.

Comment: Have you considered using a form for this? They obviously can be aware of their own name, call VBA procedures when opening and pass their name as a parameter, and close themselves thereafter (in my opinion, the more logical approach would be one form with multiple buttons for each group, and one function in which the groups get passed as parameters. You can dynamically create buttons per group).

Comment: CallByName is a very handy function to handle arbitrary macros. In your special case more details of the architecture would be needed to check whether this function would really help.

Comment: My database is a tool I've created to reverse engineer a complex 15 yr old IBM DB2 SQL db & AS400 app with 100million+ records, and many tables having 100+ columns. My macros all have only one command: RunCode(). I use them as described, in a NavPane group so I can double-click them to perform a task on other items in that group, such as transform query .SQL properties. I use the macros much like Windows shortcuts, simply to start something. Now...could someone kindly answer my question if they can..? Is it possible for a Macro to determine its own name..? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no. Macros can only execute simple commands.
Things you can do:

**List all open macros** (open as in currently being edited, not running)

```
Public Function AllMacros()
    Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object
    Set dbs = Application.CurrentProject
    ' Search for open AccessObject objects in AllMacros collection.
    For Each obj In dbs.AllMacros
    If obj.IsLoaded = True Then
    ' Print name of obj.
    Debug.Print obj.Name
    End If
    Next obj
End Function
```

**Use a form for exactly this purpose**

Create a blank form with a timer set to 1, and add the following sub (it runs MyFunction and passes the form name as a parameter)

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Me.Visible = False
    Run "MyFunction", Me.Name
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub
```

Should behave exactly as your desired macro, only it's a form not a macro

Comment: Hmm interesting tidbit that 'obj=True' is one open for editing. This solution might be a bit quirky for what I'm hoping to use it for. It seems I'm stuck, but this is not the end of the world. I'll just have to edit each copy of the macro when I drop one into a NavPane group, and hardcode it to run for only that group. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, error in copy-pasting, supposed to be obj.Loaded

Comment: oh, wasnt behind a PC, it's IsLoaded not Loaded